How to Kill player before they leave the game?
Is there a way I can use command blocks or datapacks to kill a player BEFORE they leave the game?
I want to install it in my multiplayer server, so when someone leaves the game their items will be dropped on the ground so other players can take them.
I've already tried this:
/scoreboard objectives add playerLeft minecraft.custom:minecraft.leave_game

Command Block | Repeat | Always Active:
/execute as @a[scores={playerLeft=1..}] run kill @s

Command Block | Chain | Conditional | Always Active:
/scoreboard players reset @a[scores={playerLeft=1..}] playerLeft

The problem is the player is being killed AFTER returning to the game.
I need the player dead BEFORE leaving the game...

I'm not sure it's possible technically, as we don't know when the player will leave. The only way could be to listen on spigot events and do it with plugins, else the command block will always be runned after

You could possibly do this by either catching the data of that player right as they leave and summoning another entity to drop the items, or by monitoring and storing the data the entire time.
For the first option, once you detect the player leaving, you quickly store their inventory into storage. In a repeating command block:
/execute as @a[scores={playerLeft=1..}] run summon chest_minecart ~ ~ ~ {Tags:["drop_items"]}

Then, in a chain command block:
/execute as @a[scores={playerLeft=1..}] at @s run data modify entity @e[type=chest_minecart,tag=drop_items,limit=1,sort=nearest] Items set from entity @s Inventory

Following that:
/kill @e[type=chest_minecart,tag=drop_items]

However, this might not work. It depends on how many commands can be run on players who started leaving. If the first two commands aren't able to capture the items in time, you might need the second option.
The second option relies on storing the inventory of the player constantly (or at least frequently enough), so that when they then leave the game, we just turn the data of their items into real spawned items.
Like before, you could use /data modify storage [ID] [PATH] set from entity @s Inventory. In this example, ID could be "custom:items" and PATH could be "player1". However, one downside with this is that it wouldn't work too well in multiplayer unless you somehow mapped different players to different keys in the data, or else everyone's data will be fighting for the same slot.
If you were to use this method, you would still need a way to detect when the player leaves and use that to somehow summon a chest minecart, drop in items, and then kill the minecart, and overall it's hard to use.
All of the methods I mentioned come with extra caveats, those being that a chest. minecart has much less inventory than a regular player, so the row right above the hotbar in your inventory doesn't get dropped, and the armor and offhand item don't get dropped.
Furthermore, you would also need a way of clearing the player's items when they get back, so as to not create duplicate items. If the first method works,  you could try using a /clear command in a chain command block, and afterwards reset the score. If these all manage to work in time, that might be the best it will get.
